# PostgreSQL 13 - "Vacuum full" process killed but disk does't free up

Tags: postgresql-13, vacuum

I have killed the **VACUUM FULL** was running on a database since 5 hrs.
Before initiation the disk was **286 GB** free and the **VACUUM full** took 150 GB while processing.

My question is , Why the 150 GB is not released after the process is killed?

and how can i reclaim the 150 GB back.

Please help me on this.

Comment: I have found the route-cause for this. archive segment was consuming the disk space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disk space released after clearing the logs created while Vacuum was running.